# When would I need to use makeMainActivity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I get that `makeMainActivity` basically makes the incident activity behave like a main/root activity. But I cannot see a case where I would need to use this method in android.

Would calling this method cause the activity to have a shortcut on the android device? If not, then it's not a permanent thing, and if it is not permanent, why not just use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?

Strangely enough the documentation suggests that I add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent. Thanks for any explanation.